# Display List data child to parents

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get a list of my Subcategory which contains Main Category id and name info. Please note: Subcategory is a child of the Main category. So it is like a child calling its related parents. I already tried code bellow but problem is I am getting error-

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'The ObjectContext instance has been
>   disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a
>   connection.'

I have attached the picture where u can see the error and the data debug so you will get a better understanding of my data structure coming from the database. Please ask the question if you have any confusion.

[image: debug]

[image: error]

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ProductCreate()
        {
            using (MyappWebDbEntities db = new MyappWebDbEntities())
            {
                ViewBag.SubCategories = db.SubCategories.ToList();
                return View();
            }
        }
```

View:

```
<select class="form-control" id="categoryId">
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.SubCategories)
    {
        <option value="@item.SubCategoryId">@item.SubCategoryName by-> @item.Category.CategoryName</option>
    }
    </select><br />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try replacing your subcategory fetching code with:

```
db.SubCategories.Include(x => x.Category).ToList()
```